# PHP медленно работает на Windows XP

Tags: windows, php, хостинг

Собирал еще давно сам связку WAMP. PHP 5.2.8. Особо не обращал внимание все это время, т.к. визуально не чувствовалось, но если сравнительно один скрипт магазина на дешевом хостинге работает чуть ли не в 10 раз быстрее. Также друпал у меня очень тормозит. Хотя тачка у меня вроде не слабая и программ конкурирующих нет. Если кто знает, как увеличить скорость php на windows, подскажите, плиз. Может настройки какие.

Answer (score 1):

На хостинге скорее всего стоит кешер оп-кода, а на виндовой машине - нет. Я так думаю.
eaccelerator
apc
и т.п.

Comment: хм, возможно...

Comment: Разве на хостингах ставят кэшеры ?

Comment: а на локалке акселератор стоит ставить?  
Я еще хотел потом с бенчмарками поразбираться, нагрузку потестить  
А если акселератор ставить то не исказит ли это результат теста?

Comment: я поставил, там просто нужную dll скачать и в php.ini прописать.

Результаты исказит конечно, n-ое время PHP тратит на генерацию оп-кода, с кешером это время расходоватся не будет. Вот и всё.

Comment: Вы просто определитесь что вы хотите. Или хостинг у себя на машине или dev машину. Если первое - то сами ставте связку Apache, PHP, MySQL и ещё nginx. С кешером. Правильно настроив MySQL. Что бы был и кеш большой под запросы, и вообще настроена правильно.

Comment: у меня же один мой комп, на котором я разрабатываю  
Охота и тестить, как оно в реальности потребляет, тут получается акселератор помешает  
Но охота же еще чтобы во время разработки не тупило по сильному. Для самописных скриптов я не парюсь, но с друпалом часто работаю, а вот тут уже заметно медленно все работает :(

Comment: Тогда устанавливайте eaccelerator или другой кешер. Время работы САМОГО СКРИПТА не изменится. Исчезнет время генерации этого скрипта. Друпал обязан будет быстрее работать чем без кешера. 

Не знаю как по другому написать, но просто устанавливайте и будет вам счастье :)

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас засран жесткий диск, пройдитесь по нему скандиском и дефрагментацию сделайте.
2. PHP работает в режиме cgi
3. У вас идет обращение куда-то по сети.
4. Самый действенный - попробуйте [подебажить](http://phpfaq.ru/debug). Кстати в этом вам может помочь [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/),  [небольшая дока](http://xdebug.ru/sozdanie-profajla-prilozheniya-s-xdebug), которую я не читал, но скрины похожи на правду.

Comment: xdebug-ом как раз и пользуюсь.  
Это касается всех скриптов, а не одного